# How Can I add or remove UI Components based on size class

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've been using size classes to hide and show certain views by adjusting / animating their constraints to move them in and out of view.

This is sufficient for a lot of cases but I want to see if a different approach is possible.

I want to know if it's possible to completely remove a component from the screen based on size class.

For example,

While in landscape mode I have 4 buttons on the screen.
When switching to portrait mode I remove 2 of the buttons.

Ideally I would like to achieve this using just storyboards.

Thanks,

Comment: That doesn't use auto layout or size classes

Comment: My bad . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

Comment: Try to set the width or height constraint constant value as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "remove" a control on specific size classes using the `installed` checkbox in the `Attribute inspector` :

[image]